# Horizontal Scroll-bar in ZK

Tags: textbox, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, zk

Can someone please tell me how to create a text-box with a horizontal scroll-bar like this with the help of ZKOSS (ZK) framework?

the link ->>    postimg.org/image/8ayoyfr2r/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need multiline you can do the following :

```
<textbox value="This is a long text, we need a scrollbar to see this whole sentence in the textbox." style="overflow:auto;" width="200px" height="50px"/>
```

Comment: Dear @chillworld,

Thank you for your answer, but, unfortunately when I test in in zkfiddle.org, it produces a textbox with NO-horizontal scrollbar attached to it.

Comment: I'm sorry, at work we use older IE(IE9) and with that browser it do work. Searching for newer browsers now